# React: Static method always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, static

I have a problem with a static method in React using ESLint with airbnb config. I have a service like this that is both used for creating a user in my system, and getting all the field values for the create user form. The service looks like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

import ServiceException from './ServiceException';

class CreateUserServiceException extends ServiceException {}

class CreateUserService {
  constructor(config) {
    this.apiUrl = config.API_URL;
    this.userDomain = config.USER_DOMAIN;
  }

  static getFormFields() {
    return [
      {
        id: 'username',
        type: 'text',
        title: 'E-postadress',
        placeholder: 'Användarnamn',
        mandatory: true,
        extra: '',
      },
      {
        id: 'password',
        type: 'password',
        title: 'Lösenord',
        placeholder: 'Lösenord',
        mandatory: true,
        extra: '',
      },
    ];
  }

  async createUser(data) {
    try {
      await axios.post(`${this.apiUrl}/users/${this.userDomain}`, data, { withCredentials: true });
    } catch ({ response }) {
      throw new CreateUserServiceException(
        response.status, 'Failed to create user', response.data,
      );
    }
  }
}

export default CreateUserService;
```

I also have a jsx controller to create my form. This controller gets the service via it's properties. The controller looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';

import './index.css';

class CreateUserController extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      formFields: [],
      userData: {},
    };

    this.onCreate = this.onCreate.bind(this);
    this.onLoad = this.onLoad.bind(this);
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.onLoad();
  }

  async onLoad() {
    const { createUserService } = await this.props;
    const { getFormFields } = createUserService;
    const formFields = getFormFields || []; // ALWAYS RETURNS UNDEFINED
    const userData = {};

    console.log(formFields); // ALWAYS DISPLAYS []

    formFields.forEach((field) => {
      userData[field.id] = '';
    });

    this.setState({ formFields, userData });
  }

  async onCreate(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { userData } = this.state;
    console.log(userData);
  }

  render() {
    const { userData, formFields } = this.state;

    return (
      <section className="create-user-controller">
        <h1>Skapa ny användare</h1>
        <form
          className="centered-container"
          action=""
          noValidate
          onSubmit={this.onCreate}
        >
          <table>
            <tbody>
              {formFields.map(field => (
                <tr key={field.id}>
                  <td>{field.title}</td>
                  <td>
                    <input
                      value={userData[field.id]}
                      onChange={e => this.setState({
                        userData: { ...userData, [field.id]: e.target.value },
                      })}
                      className={`create-${field.id}`}
                      name={field.id}
                      placeholder={field.placeholder}
                      type={field.type}
                    />
                  </td>
                  <td>{field.extra}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
              <tr>
                <td colSpan={3}>* obligatoriskt</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <input type="submit" className="btn btn-green" value="Skapa användare" />
        </form>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default CreateUserController;
```

My problem is that `const formFields = getFormFields || [];` always becomes `[]` which means that `getFormFields` always returns undefined.

If I remove `static` from `getFormFields()` in my service and call it using `const formFields = createUserService.getFormFields();` it works fine, but then ESLint complains about `ESLint: Expected 'this' to be used by class method 'getFormFields'. (class-methods-use-this)`.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: shouldn't be *const formFields = getFormFields() || [];* ? invoke the func to get the return

Comment: @Roy.B Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: is this:  const formFields = getFormFields || []; // ALWAYS RETURNS UNDEFINED should be this: const formFields = getFormFields() || []; ? can you try?

Comment: @Roy.B That gives me `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): getFormFields is not a function`.

Comment: please also change this const { getFormFields } = createUserService; to this const { getFormFields } = CreateUserService;

Comment: and don't get it from props, you need to import the class CreateUserService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import CreateUserService from './CreateUserService';
...
async onLoad() {
    ...
    const formFields = CreateUserService.getFormFields() || [];
    ...
}
```

Should do the trick !
Notice that the static function is called using the Class name. Tou will also have to import it correctly (i don't know your path…)

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, I cannot use static functions when sending the Class via props?

Comment: @BluePrint A static method needs to be accessed on the class not through an instance.

Comment: @BluePrint exactly ! Please mark as answered if that was your issue ;)